# How to get console responses in sequence?

Tags: powershell, logging, wait

I am using the library 'Logging' module to handle writes to the console and to a log file.
At the end of the script I have a 'Pause' to ensure that when the script is run the command window does not close before I can peruse it.
So my code is:

```
Write-Log -Level 'DEBUG' -Message 'Debug level message
Write-Log -Level 'INFO' -Message 'Info level message' 
Write-Log -Level 'WARNING' -Message 'Warning level message' -Body @{source = 'Logging'}
Write-Log -Level 'ERROR' -Message 'Error level message'
Write-Log -Level 'INFO' -Message '********** IS FINISHING ************************'
```

Pause

```
The console output is:

> [DEBUG  ] Debug level message
> [INFO   ] Info level message
> Press Enter to continue...: [WARNING] Warning level message
> [ERROR  ] Error level message
> [INFO   ] ********** IS FINISHING ************************

As you can see, the 'Pause' is displayed in the middle of the Write-Log console display messages.
I thought of putting a wait before the Pause but it seems a bit naff.
Is there a proper way of dealing with this?
```

Comment: I've only glanced at the module and its documentation, but found this: "When used in unattended scripts (scheduled tasks, spawned process) you [need to call `Wait-Logging` to avoid losing messages."](https://github.com/RootITUp/Logging/wiki#note), so perhaps calling `Wait-Logging` before the `pause` helps (though perhaps that's what you meant by "putting a wait before the `pause`"). `Wait-Logging` ["Wait(s) for the message queue to be emptied"](https://github.com/RootITUp/Logging/wiki/Wait%E2%80%90Logging)

Comment: @mklement0 You've got it exactly right; putting Wait-Logging after the block of Write-Logs holds up the processing until the message queue is emptied and then allows the next command, which in my case is 'Pause', to run. All works fine now. Many, many thanks

Comment: My pleasure, @Davy; I've written up a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the [`Logging` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Logging)'s [`Write-Log`](https://github.com/RootITUp/Logging/wiki/Write%E2%80%90Log) function uses a *queue* for storing the given messages and therefore doesn't guarantee *synchronous* display output.

To ensure that all messages in the queue have been processed and the corresponding host (display) output printed, you must use the [`Wait-Logging`](https://github.com/RootITUp/Logging/wiki/Wait%E2%80%90Logging) command.

As you've confirmed, placing `Wait-Logging` before the `pause` command in your script resulted in the desired display output.